# How to get embedded video to be responsive in a shrunk browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

So I have the embedded video the way I like it in the full width browser, but when it is shrunk to the small size browser and below, I can't figure out a way to get to be responsive, so it stays centered in the browser.

I am using Bootstrap's grid system for the text next to it to be responsive. I would like for the video to be stacked underneath the text when the browser hits medium size and below, and I have successfully made the video centered with media query when it's in the medium  size browser, but can't get it centered in the small and extra small browser size. Does this make sense?

```css
.section1Text {
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.section1Text h2 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 2.9em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.section1Btn {
  background-color: #2e3233;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
  border-color: #121313;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 1.45em;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.video-responsive {
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  float: right;
}

.video-responsive iframe {
  width: 560px;
  height: 315px;
}


/*section1 media queries*/

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .video-responsive {
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    margin-right: 35px;
  }
  .video-responsive iframe {
    width: 672px;
    height: 378px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="section1Text col-md-4">
        <h2 class="text-center">What We Have to Offer</h2>
        <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel massa iaculis, posuere augue et, pharetra ipsum. Suspendisse metus ex, pellentesque id dolor in, vehicula varius tortor. Nam auctor ante nisi.</p>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
          <a class="btn section1Btn btn-block" href="#">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="video-responsive">
        <iframe width="560px" height="315px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bsY2GdBEvSA?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the videos responsiveness, use percents (example below). Mess around with the percents until it works the way you would like it. You may also need a container to put the video in.

```
.video-responsive iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried before and I even tried again, but that does not work with an embedded video.

Comment: Where are you getting the video from?

Comment: It's embedded from youtube

Comment: Make a separate container other than the .video-responsive iframe{} class. Try making a  .container { width: 100%; height: 50%; }